# Fixed menu, (optional) fixed submenu and area for content for a dashboard with CSS

Tags: css

I want to reproduce the next image for a website backend:

[image]

The idea is to have a fixed area (sidebar) that will contain a menu and a submenu and all the other area, the content, can navigate up and down without affecting to that sidebar.

I need that the width of the sidebar can be changed, so content will adapt his width too because in some pages it's probably that will be no submenu.

I've been playing with floats, but I think I'm not sketching good the layar.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HUhfU/5/

```
<div id="main" style="width:100%;border:1px solid red;">
    <div id="sidemenu" style="float:left;height:200px;width:150px;border:1px solid green;">
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;">
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        .....
        .....
        I just filled up the content to show the scroll working
        .....
        .....
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
    </div>
</div>
```